# Given a MAC address, can I determine what device it is through QTerminal?

Tags: networking, lubuntu, 18.10, network-monitoring

The home router webpage lists connected MAC addresses. Is there a way to determine what the device is (e.g. iPad, PS3, Nintendo Switch, Windows laptop) and info about it (e.g. name input by its user) without physically accessing the device? Are there commands I can execute in QTerminal?

Comment: The closest you can do is take the MAC address and look up the MAC address online to figure the type of chip it is.  Keep in mind that with some of the devices you can *change* the system to masquerade as a different MAC Address.  I.E. as an example I have my laptop masquerade as the MAC address of the Android phone I have when I am at work, so it doesn't look like the system is actually a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

The first 3 Bytes of a MAC-address are assigned to the manufacturer, so in principle it is possible/easy to find the first part of your question.

I don't know about any downloadable database that contains those relations though (apart from installing wireshark, which has one built in but thats overkill here). So you would take the first 3 parts of any mac-address (like `90:5c:44`) and google it.

Be aware that it is easy to spoof a MAC address - so don't make security decisions based on that information.

However there is no way to find any local modifications without direct access to the other machine.

Comment: The downloadable database that you don't know about can be found here: http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt